# Embedding SVG in ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, svg

I would like to embed svg directly into my ASP.net-MVC view so that the output looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <svg> ... </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

With PHP I would do this like so:

```
<? include('image.svg'); ?>
```

I tried `@Html.Partial('image.svg')` but got an error. Is there a way to fix this or another method I can try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Embed your SVG into a cshtml view file instead of a .svg file, then you should be able to use @Html.Partial to render it.

Your partial would then look like

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/pathtosvg/svg.cshtml")`

Comment: This can't be the best solution. What if you have +200 SVG files?? Are you going to rename them all and keep a copy of both? Maybe by creating some task in gulp, but it seems to me that there must be a better solution

Comment: i add something to this answer. if you have very big svg file this solution will not work and you should use @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/image.svg"))) in your code.

Answer (score 26):

Renaming SVG files and using Html.Partial should do the trick, but I didn't like to be renaming files in order to achieve it. So, this way, you can keep your files as they are.

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/image.svg")))
```

Comment: How would this be combined with an img tag in html?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use just file include same as php file?

Example:

```
<!--#include file="image.svg"-->
```

This syntax should work similar to php include, but for asp.net

Comment: That just serves the html comment to the browser :-\

Comment: This should include the file in asp.net, I tried it just now. It is explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp