# Load SVG contained within a HTML page to an .aspx page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, svg

I have a **svg.html** file where the svg content are defined within a  element.
I've been combing the Internet for 3 days now, have not found a solution as to why the icons I use don't show up on the rendered **.aspx** web pages. svg.html looks like this:

```
<div class="svg-icons">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-icons">
<symbol id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
<path d="##path value##"></path>
</symbol>
</svg>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

1. using the `<object></object>` tags referring to svg.html.
2. `<use>` tags.
3. In web.config `<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />`

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I cannot change the svg.html file, and this is an *ASP.Net web form*s project.

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478812/embedding-svg-in-asp-net-page

Comment: @UpendraJoshi please note that I cannot change the svg.html file, and this is an Asp.Net web forms project.

Comment: Are your HTML pages having complete markup (including `<html>` & `<head>` tags? If it doesn't, you can proceed to create a user control & insert the HTML page reference there with `iframe`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Could you please elaborate on how to insert the `<iframe>` tag? I used the tag earlier but the icons still didn't show up.

Comment: It depends on SVG usage (raw file or embedding). In case of raw SVG, you can use virtual path: `<iframe src="~/path_to_file_SVG.svg" />`. But if you're embed SVG into an HTML file markup, use `Literal` placeholder instead & parsing around `<svg>` tag.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto none of it worked. Using `<iframe>` caused the svg file to be downloaded whenever the page loads. I ended up moving the svg code from the external file to the aspx file itself. Thank you for all your helpful suggestions. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have complete markup inside html file containing SVG image, you can place a literal control & assign the HTML page contents from code behind by stripping unnecessary markups with regex:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Literal ID="placeholder" runat="server" />
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string html;
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/path_to_html_file.html"))
    {
        html = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }

    Regex start = new Regex(@"[\s\S]*<body[^<]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    html = start.Replace(html, "");
    Regex end = new Regex(@"</body[\s\S]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    html = end.Replace(html, "");

    placeholder.Text = html;

}
```

If you have raw SVG file and want to use it in literal tag element, you can simply use `<iframe src="/path_to_SVG_file.svg" />`/`<embed src="/path_to_SVG_file.svg" />` inside user control, or a `div` assigned with `InnerHtml` attribute:

**ASPX**

```
<div id="placeholder" runat="server"></div>
```

**Code-behind**

```
placeholder.InnerHtml = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/path_to_SVG_file.svg"));
```

References:

[Include contents of an html page in an aspx page](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/33/include-contents-of-an-html-page-in-an-aspx-page)

[Interactive Mapping Using SVG & ASP.NET](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/drawing/article.php/c19577/Interactive-Mapping-Using-SVG--ASPNET.htm)